# Keeping Pages in its own folder?

Tags: file, directory

I'm wondering if it would be okay to keep all of my pages in one folder on a site. and leave only the index.html page in `public_html`?

I know the URL will be like example.com/pages/about.html but theirs a way to change that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fine. Theres no reason why it should be a problem. And theres no reason why there should be a problem with your URL being example.com/pages/about.html. If you prefer that, then you do that... its fine.

You can always "mask" your URLs using MOD_REWRITE. Look up mod_rewrite and .htaccess files. You will be able to set a rule to "mask" something.html to pages/something.html. Its not hard to do.

:)

Comment: I just like to keep my stuff clean and tidy. and theres A LOT of files in public_html

Comment: that's fine. :) you can put any files anywhere you want (in public_html). Just make sure all your links are pointing to the right place.